# How do I deal with casting error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, casting, error-handling

I am trying to catch a `System.InvalidCastException` error. If I put a number into the calculator the program runs ok. If the calculate button is pressed with nothing in the text boxes I get the casting error `Conversion from string "" to type 'Decimal' is not valid.` I understand why I am getting the error. I don't know what to do about it. I want the program to dump null data and go back to waiting for input from the user. Thanks

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
  Dim FedTaxRate = 0.13     ' constants for taxes and work week
  Dim StateTaxRate = 0.07
  Dim StandWorkWeek = 40
  Dim GrossPay As Decimal    ' variables
  Dim NetPay As Decimal


  If txtInWage.Text = "" Then
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the wage box", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
  End If


  If txtInHours.Text = "" Then
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the hours box", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
  End If

  Dim decInHours = CDec(txtInHours.Text) 'converts text boxes to numerical data
  Dim decInWage = CDec(txtInWage.Text)


  If decInHours <= StandWorkWeek Then        'calculates gross and net pay as well as taxes. Also includes overtime after 40 hours
    GrossPay = (decInHours * decInWage)
  ElseIf decInHours > StandWorkWeek Then
    GrossPay = (decInWage * StandWorkWeek) + (decInHours - StandWorkWeek) * (decInWage * 1.5)
  End If

  NetPay = GrossPay - (GrossPay * FedTaxRate) - (GrossPay * StateTaxRate)

  lblGrossPay.Text = GrossPay.ToString("c")
  lblNetPay.Text = NetPay.ToString("c")
  lblFedTax.Text = (GrossPay * FedTaxRate).ToString("c")
  lblStateTax.Text = (GrossPay * StateTaxRate).ToString("C")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting input from a `TextBox` then it is possible the user may enter letters, in which case `CDec` will also fail.

You could use [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) instead.

```
Dim decInHours As Decimal
Dim decInWage As Decimal    
If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtInHours.Text, decInHours) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the hours box", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        Exit Sub ' As in answer from Fredou.
End If

If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtInWage.Text, decInWage) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the wage box", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        Exit Sub ' As in answer from Fredou.
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
If txtInWage.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the wage box", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    exit sub
End If
```